# Solaris local users querying centralized LDAP

Tags: ldap, solaris, users, local

I have a centralized posix ldap that store some users and a lot of solaris servers that points to.

The users stored in ldap are able to authenticate on solaris servers.
When I look to ldap access logs, there are a lot of queries from solaris local users.

My nsswitch.conf has passwd and groups as this: files ldap

I think solaris see files and ldap as a single repository.

Is there a way to avoid local users perform queries on ldap?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are the users trying to find in the LDAP queries you see?

Comment: That is the binddn query. The goal of this query is check if the user exists on ou=people branch.